# how can i shuffle this react code to be compared and matched with that of the data collection in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, shuffle

> `
>
> ```
> eslint-disable import/no-anonymous-default-export */
> export default [{
> id: 1,
> Question: "Javascript is an ______ language",
> options: [
>             "Object-oriented",
>             "Object-based",
>             "Procedural"
>         ],
> answerIndex: 0
>     },
>     //continue adding questions
> ];
> this is my backend array
> export const answers = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0];`
>
> `my react shuffled code 
> import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
> import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
> import { getServerData } from "../helper/helper.jsx";
> import * as Action from "../redux/question_reducer.jsx";
>
> export const useFetchQuestion = () => {
> const dispatch = useDispatch();
> const [getData, setGetData] = useState({
> isLoading: false,
> apiData: [],
> serverError: null,
>   });
>
> useEffect(() => {
> setGetData((prev) => ({ ...prev, isLoading: true }));
>     (async () => {
> try {
> const [{ questions, answers }] = await getServerData(
>           `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_HOSTNAME}/api/questions`,
>           (data) => data
>         );
>
> if (questions.length > 0) {
> shuffle the questions */
>
> setGetData((prev) => ({ ...prev, isLoading: false }));
> setGetData((prev) => ({ ...prev, apiData: questions, answers }));
>
> dispatch(Action.startExamAction({ question: questions, answers }));
> else {
> throw new Error("No Question Available");
>         }
> catch (error) {
> setGetData((prev) => ({ ...prev, isLoading: false }));
> setGetData((prev) => ({ ...prev, serverError: error }));
>       }
>     })();
> [dispatch]);
>
> return [getData, setGetData];
> };
>
>
> /**MoveNextAction Dispatch function */
> export const MoveNextQuestion = () => (dispatch) =>
> new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
> try {
> dispatch(Action.moveNextAction()); /** increase trace by 1 */
> resolve();
> catch (error) {
> console.log(error);
> reject(error);
>     }
>   });
>
> /**MovePrevAction Dispatch function */
> export const MovePrevQuestion = () => (dispatch) =>
> new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
> try {
> dispatch(Action.movePrevAction()); /** decrease trace by 1 */
> resolve();
> catch (error) {
> console.log(error);
> reject(error);
>     }
>   });`
> ```

The problem I have is that when I click at the options and submit in the console it returns different index array cause it being shuffled I want it to be compared and match cause if not even thou I click at the right answers it will still give me wrong answer cause of the shuffled react code but if I remove the shuffled code everything works fine so how can I solve this query.

> `React component.
> eslint-disable eqeqeq */
> eslint-disable no-template-curly-in-string */
> eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
> import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
>
> import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
>
> /**Custom Hook */
> import { useFetchQuestion } from "../hooks/FetchQuestion";
> import { updateResult } from "../hooks/setResult";
>
> export default function Questions({ onChecked }){
>
> const [checked, setChecked] = useState(undefined)
> const { trace } = useSelector(state => state.questions);
> const result = useSelector(state => state.result.result);
>
> const [{ isLoading,  serverError}] = useFetchQuestion()
>
> const  questions  = useSelector(state => state.questions.queue[state.questions.trace])
> const dispatch = useDispatch()
>
> useEffect(() => {
> dispatch(updateResult({ trace, checked }))
> eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
> [checked])
>
> function onSelect(i){
> onChecked(i)
> setChecked(i)
>
> dispatch(updateResult({ trace, checked  }))
> }
>
> if(isLoading) return isLoading
> if(serverError) return {serverError || "Unknown Error"}
>
> return (
>
> {questions?.Question}
>
> ```
>        <ul key={questions?.id}>
>       {
> ```
>
> questions?.options.map((q, i) => (
>
> <input
> type="radio"
> value={false}
> name="options"*
> id={`q${i}-option`}
> onChange={() => onSelect(i)}
> />
>
> ```
>                     <label className="text-primary" htmlFor={`q${i}-option`}>{q}</label>
>                     <div className={`check ${result[trace] == i ? 'checked' : ''}`}></div>
>                 </li>
>             ))
>           }
>            </ul>
> ```
>
> ```
>     </div>
> )
> ```
>
> }`

have tried using value instead of the index array but still not working.